# java does not run with j-grasp on my iMac

Tags: jgrasp

I am getting this error when I try to run Java with j-grasp:

```
 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Palindrome.java
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports javac.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.


 ----jGRASP wedge: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to download and install one of the "bundled" versions of jGRASP, which comes with Java and will prefer that java and javac over all others.

If you are unable to do that, you can turn on "Settings" > "Verbose Messages" in jGRASP then compile to see what "javac" is actually running ("actual command sent" in the verbose output). Most likely it is not a "normal" javac, since the error message doesn't look like I would expect - I don't know what this "java.com" website is. If you do have a normal Java installation, deleting that rogue "javac" may fix the problem.